# Finding text in PDFs without using 'pdftotext' command line tool, but its API instead

Tags: c++, pdf, pdftotext

I'd like to find texts and their bounding boxes in PDF files.

The tool that seems to work the best is `pdftotext` (XPDF-based).

However I have not been able to figure out how one can use this tool without a commandline nor have I found a non-commandline API. I'd like to be able to use this in a C++ program without using a system call.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`pdftotext` (XPDF) has a (forked) sibling based on the **[Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)** library, which was forked from the XPDF code base 10 years ago.

Poppler's source code repository is here:

- **[CGit Interface to Poppler Repository](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler)**

There you should easily find out how to use Poppler's C++ API.